# Why are iframe requests not sending cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, security, iframe, cross-domain, content-security-policy

A sibling department has created an HTML file that is effectively a scaffold for a handful of iframes. The iframes each call a report, which is hosted on a web server, with slightly different parameters. The called report will show a sign-on form to unauthenticated users, or the report contents to already-authenticated users.

scaffold.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>I just show the output from a bunch of report calls</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe src="https://somesite.com/useful_report.html?parameter1=a&parameter2=1" id="iframe1"></iframe>
      <iframe src="https://somesite.com/useful_report.html?parameter1=b&parameter2=2" id="iframe2"></iframe>
      <iframe src="https://somesite.com/useful_report.html?parameter1=c&parameter2=3" id="iframe3"></iframe>
      <iframe src="https://somesite.com/useful_report.html?parameter1=d&parameter2=4" id="iframe4"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

The sibling organization explained to us that if a user was signed on to https://somesite.com, the above setup worked great--each of the iframes would display the useful_report.html content...until a few days ago.

When I

1. sign on to https://somesite.com, then
2. load file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/scaffold.html into Chrome

each of the iframes returns the https://somesite.com sign on form. If I then open useful_report.html in a separate tab, the report content loads (proving somesite.com knows I am still signed on‡).

Using developer tools, I can see that the request headers to useful_report.html do not include the "Cookie:" attribute, so this explains why useful_report.html returns the sign on form.

My question is **why are the iframe requests not sending cookies?** What Chrome and/or server setting/policy/directive prevents it?

‡ - and now it knows that I know that it knows.

Comment: Is `somesite.com` setting `SameSite` in its cookie? https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4672634709082112

Comment: @cody I am looking at the cookie, but I don't see any attributes by that name (or similar). Is the `SameSite` attribute something I would be able to see in Developer Tools?

Comment: yeah, you would see it as a name/value pair in the cookie in developer tools, like session id or anything else.. scratch that off the list I guess

Comment: Can you quickly fire up a local http server, serve the file with the iframes via that, and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @cody Yes, it does make a difference; when hosted on somesite.com, scaffold.html iframes load the report content (the request headers include the cookie).

Comment: HI @JeromyFrench do not think this has anything to do with `content-security-policy`. Any reason why you have added `content-security-policy` tag? Do you have `csp` in place? if yes, does it works without it?

Comment: @AnkitVijay I suspect a content-security-policy setting is at play here (based on something I read while researching this before posting my question), but I'm reaching. I don't know enough about the subject--how CSP works--to rule it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because of the **SameSite** cookie policy that [Chrome defaults to Lax](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592), meaning the cookies won't be sent unless the user can see the URL which excludes iframes.

If you own the *somesite.com* you can opt-out of this policy by setting SameSite policy to None and deal with the risk of CSRF attacks by [Double Submit Cookie](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie).