# Chrome not sending back cookies in iframe after Aug 10, 2020 update

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, iframe, cross-site

We have a webapp that embed another webapp on a different site in an iFrame. This had been in place for a few years already. Last week we started to get error reports from some users. After investigation we found that on Chrome 84.0.4147.125, released Aug 10, 2020, the cookies in the iFrame are not sent back to the server. The issue only occurs since this chrome version. Older versions and other browsers are working fine.

What has changed in this release that could have this impact?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094712/iframe-not-reading-cookies-in-chrome

Comment: @Eyal.D, yes this was the issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Eyal.D for pointing to the solution.

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095345/1401409 :

> Chrome now blocks cookies without `SameSite` set, so you need to
> explicitly set it to `samesite=none`.

I was able to fix this by adding the following in my httpd configuration:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None
```

I would add, as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874184/1401409 :

> If you own the somesite.com you can opt-out of this policy by setting
> SameSite policy to None and deal with the risk of CSRF attacks by a
> doing [Double Submit Cookie](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie).

Comment: For those using tomcat This can be fixed by adding  `<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none" />` in META-INF/context.xml under Context section. also make sure to set `secure=true` attribute in HTTPS connector in server.xml

Comment: I had success with that. Using session_cookie_set_param in PHP 7.3 doesn’t give expected results.

Comment: how do I add the same settings in an webview mobile app ?

Comment: @Lint, I'm not familiar with webview, but from what I see it's a client. You would need to to put these directives on the server.